# Rotational invariance of Laplace-Beltrami eigenvalue problem on smooth manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, differential-operators

I am currently looking at the eigenvalue problems of the Laplace-Beltrami operator. Let $(M,g$) be a smooth and oriented Riemann manifold. I am investigating the eigenvalue problem of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $M$. The Laplace-Beltrami operator is given by
$$ \Delta f = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_{i}\left(\sqrt{|g|}g^{ij}\partial_{j}f \right),$$
where $g:=\operatorname{det}(g_{ij})$ and $g_{ij}$ are the components of the metric tensor and $g^{ij}$ are the entries of the inverse metric tensor.

I want to show (if its true) that the Helmholtz-equation i.e., the eigenvalue problem of the Laplace Beltrami operator,
\begin{equation}
\Delta u = \lambda u \qquad \qquad \text{in } M
\end{equation}
and,
\begin{equation}
u = 0 \qquad \qquad \text{on } \partial M
\end{equation}
$$ $$
is rotation invariant, i.e., if $(\lambda, u(x))$ is a solution to the Helmholtz equation in $M$ then $(\lambda, v(x))$ with
$$ v(x) = u(Qx)$$
for some unitary matrix $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$is a solution to the Helmholtz-equation on $\widetilde{M}=\{ y|y=Qx, x \in M\}="QM"$.

Intuitively the statement makes sense since the Laplace-Beltrami operator only takes the local geometry into account. Thus, I would expect that the rotated eigenfunctions should be a solution to the rotated problem. I managed to prove the same statement for the classical Laplace operator. However, since in the Laplace-Beltrami operator both $g$ and $g^{ij}$ non-trivially depend on $x$, straight-forward calculations quickly became unfeasible. I also could not find a proof or counterexample in literature.

Comment: As it stands, the setting is pretty unclear (at least to me): how do the unitary matrices $Q$ act on points $x$ in $M$? Is $M$ to be assumed already embedded into $\mathbb{C}^n$? Or is there a group action given? Then you would need that the metric is invariant under this group action...?